# Which neo4j OGM 2.x versions to use with gradle

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Could anyone please suggest the latest neo4j 2.x OGM version to be used with gradle as a compile dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.0.1 with these dependencies:

```
 compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:2.0.1'
```

and the [appropriate driver](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/#_dependencies_for_the_neo4j_ogm).

Comment: Thanks Luanne. Is this the latest version that can be used with gradle.

Comment: 2.0.1 is the latest release. 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT the latest in terms of snapshots, but not fit for production